# Find and move files based on filenames in txt file oneline

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, find

I'm sure I had a working oneliner that allowed me to search a directory (or .) for files containing names matching names in a txt file and copying these to a new directory.

Somehow I cannot get it to work - any help please.

Sorry if this is a duplicate - I have really searched for an answer (here and elsewhere), but cannot find a solution.

foo/movehere/sample.txt file:

```
141516
141619
```

Files I want to find and move i.e.:

```
foo/folder/folder2/141516_S2_R1.fastq.gz
foo/folder/folder2/141516_S2_R1.fastq.gz
```

Where I want to move them:

```
foo/movehere/
```

my current (nonfunctioning) oneliner:

```
while read -r FILE; do find . -name "$FILE*.fastq.gz" -type f -exec cp {} /foo/movehere/ \;;done </foo/movehere/sample.txt
```

There are some errors in the oneliner. It still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `eval` in your code

```
SEARCH="-name '$FILE*.fastq.gz'"
eval "find . $SEARCH -type f exec cp '{}' /foo/movehere/ \";
```

**security note : *do not put user supplied data into eval.***

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I should delete the post - but I'll leave my solution here if anyone else encounter the exact same problem.

Still not 100% sure I understand why it failed, but I got the oneliner working by copying all the sample names from the txt to a unedited file with no suffix.

I guess some (hidden) "\r" editing in the txt file messed up the "$FILE" so that it searched for something like this:

```
151617*fastq.gz\r
```

Perhaps someone with a better understanding of terminal scripts may confirm this.

EDIT 190128: happened across my old question, and just in case anyone struggle with something similar, make sure you have UNIX or similar line shifts, my txt files had weird window line shifts.